# How to enable browserify transform only in one environment

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I have a project layout like this:

```
gulpfile.js
node_modules/
    foo/
    bar/
```

Where the `foo/` and `bar/` modules are actually my own code for which I want to apply Browserify transforms. (This is a hack to avoid relative paths like `require("../../blah")`, instead being able to write `require("foo/pkg/blah")`.)

Because of the way Browserify works, I need to have a `package.json` file within both foo/ and bar/ modules, with contents like that:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": ["rewireify"]
  }
}
```

Otherwise Browserify would only apply the transform to the root module, but not on the submodules.

But I'd like to apply the `rewireify` transform only when running tests (it's adding dependency injection code to each module which I don't want to include to the production build).

But disabling `rewireify` transform at the top level doesn't affect the submodules.

Is there a way to enable some Browserify transforms only in some environment? Or maybe a way to only enable some `package.json` settings based on environment?

**PS.** I've found a workaround by hacking the `rewireify` transform source, but it would be nice to achieve it so that I wouldn't need to fork a transform.